# Does Google Sheets/Docs have a desktop client?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-workspace-for-business

Other web apps like [Trello](https://itunes.apple.com/app/trello/id1278508951?ls=1&mt=12) and [Airtable](https://airtable.com/downloads) have desktop versions of the app via  [electron.js](http://github.com/electron/electron). Is there a similar solution (provided by Google or 3rd party) for Google Sheets or any other G suite apps?

Answer (score 3):

Google used to offer Google Docs Editors desktop apps through the Chrome Apps but they were retired. At this time it's possible to do some tasks by enabling offline access (available only on Chrome) like editing files but it's not possible to some features like Google Apps Script as it run on Google's servers. For further details see [Work on Google Docs, Sheets, & Slides offline](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102?hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

No, Google does not offer a desktop version of either Docs or Sheets that would run outside of a browser.

I suppose there might be some third-party applications that could do that, but seeking them here amounts to an app recommendation request, which are off-topic. For that, try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an official Google application, but this is might be what you're looking for.

https://github.com/alexkim205/G-Desktop-Suite

> G Desktop Suite is a desktop wrapper for Google Drive built with ElectronJS.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted but this seems like a viable solution to my question

Answer (score 0):

This is a hackish workaround, but you could use [Fluid App](https://fluidapp.com/) to generate a native webview that points to drive.google.com.

Here's how it looks on my dock:

[image: Dock]

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I am currently using for several Google services is the "Install as app" option in the beta version of Microsoft Edge. Install Edge Beta, navigate to Sheets, Docs, YouTube Music, Google Podcasts, or whatever site, choose the "Apps" option from the three dots menu, and "Install this site as an app." It's basically just a wrapper for the website, but it will give you a distinctive icon on your task bar separated out from all your Chrome tabs.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is still an issue, but Windows store now has an app that you can download. Docs for Google documents charges you 3.99 for 10 licenses.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp): clasp allows you to develop your Apps Script projects locally. That means you can check-in your code into source control, collaborate with other developers, and use your favorite tools to develop Apps.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's able to download it through *extra instruments* menu in Chrome settings. Just follow *3 dots* > *extra instruments* > *make an app (label)*. Finally it will save any web-page like it is an .html-file (not certain 'bout it) but with an icon of the page. On Macs it will be an .app format...

Comment: Chrome hasn't "extra instruments"